# Importing NPM Module

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6, npm-publish, npm-package

I have just forked a github project, made some changes and added it to my project.  The problem is, I can't figure out how to import it into my project

I tried this import statement:

```
import Editor from 'editorjs-react'
```

But it didn't work.  Truth be told, I have no idea what I am supposed to try (this is the first time that I have ever created an npm package).

Here is the project:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/editorjs-react

Any ideas/suggestions of how to get this to work?

Comment: Did you tried `import Editor from '@stfy/react-editor.js'` ? It's in description of package

Comment: That works -- but I don't know why and I don't know how to change it (which I'd like to do).  Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you change it ? This name is because when he uploaded that package, he included also it with his nickname on NPM

Comment: Basically -- so I can learn how NPM works.  I have forked his project, made some minor changes and uploaded my new version under a new name on NPM.  I therefore want the include statement to reference that new name (not the name of the original project).